# make div fullscreen on click using angular js only

Tags: angularjs

I just need to make a div fullscreen whenever a user clicks on that div. I know this can be done via javascript and jquery. But i want to know if there is any pure angular js method of doing it. Any suggestions in this regard would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `ngClass` to apply a fullscreen class based on a boolean scope property. And use `ngClick` to toggle the scope property when clicked...

```
<div ng-click="isFullScreen = !isFullScreen" 
     ng-class="{fullscreen: isFullScreen}">click me</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U9LVN/)

Comment: This isn't full-screen, merely full-container

Answer (score 4):

You can use a fullscreen directive like this ones:

https://github.com/hrajchert/angular-screenfull

https://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen

Answer (score 2):

Making a div fullscreen is(should be) about css, so you can change your div's css class via angular like:

html

```
<div ng-class="{fullScreenDiv: isFullScreen}">...</div>
<div ng-click="makeFullScreen()"></div>
```

js

```
$scope.isFullScreen = false;
$scope.makeFullScreen = function(){
    $scope.isFullScreen = true;
};
```

fullScreenDiv is css class and isFullScreen is a variable in your controller scope. Change isFullScreen variable to enable/disable full screen.

Meaining of `ng-class="{fullScreenDiv: isFullScreen}"` is if `isFullScreen` expression evaluates to true then apply `fullScreenDiv` css class to element.